# Moving members of class passed as a const reference argument

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdtuple

Considering:

```
template <typename... Args>
ResourceHolder& operator+=(const ResourceInserter<Key, Args...>& inserter) {

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0) {
        insert(std::move(inserter.key),
               std::move(inserter.fileName));
    } else {
        insert(std::move(inserter.key),
               std::move(inserter.fileName),
               std::move(std::get<Args...>(inserter.tuple)));
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Do you think this is a correct usage of move semantics?

The `inserter` instance of `ResourceInserter` is passed as a const reference.

Comment: moving const objects is generally a simple copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving const objects is generally a simple copy (unless you overload `Object(const Object&&)`) so your usage of `std::move` seems useless.

If the members of `ResourceInserter` are (non-const) references,
your `const ResourceInserter&` is "misleading", and your move will actually happen.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You are casting to `const Key &&` etc. `Key::Key(const Key&&)` generally can't do anything useful, so you will be copying.

You *might* want to have a pair of overloads

```
template <typename... Args>
ResourceHolder& operator+=(const ResourceInserter<Key, Args...>& inserter) {

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0) {
        insert(inserter.key,
               inserter.fileName);
    } else {
        insert(inserter.key,
               inserter.fileName,
               std::get<Args...>(inserter.tuple));
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename... Args>
ResourceHolder& operator+=(ResourceInserter<Key, Args...>&& inserter) {

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0) {
        insert(std::move(inserter.key),
               std::move(inserter.fileName));
    } else {
        insert(std::move(inserter.key),
               std::move(inserter.fileName),
               std::move(std::get<Args...>(inserter.tuple)));
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Where you move from the members of an rvalue `inserter`

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to it's name, [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) doesn't actually move anything. It merely tells the compiler to try to move (i.e., indicate that an object `t` may be "moved from" by casting it to rvalue reference type [more specifically, by producing [xvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)]).

However, your class has no constructor that accepts a `const inserter&&`, it will instead use the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) of your class (either implicit or explicit), and safely copy. No danger, no trap. If the copy constructor is disabled for any reason, you will get a compilation error.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Test {
   Test() { }
   Test(const Test& ) { std::cout << "COPY" << std::endl; }
   Test(Test&&)       { std::cout << "MOVE" << std::endl; }
};

int main() 
{
    const Test t;
    Test t2 = std::move(t);
    return 0;
}
```

prints `COPY`, not `MOVE`.